# I get the "NameError: not defined" even if it is defined on a previous cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

So I'm learning about machine learning algorithms and I don't know why I'm getting this `NameError: name ' ' is not defined` even if it is defined on a previous cell (I'm using the jupyter notebook).

In the code below, as you can see, I've defined some names and imported `numpy`, and when I try to run the last cell (In[1]), I get the name error and the import problem.

If I copy the defined names from the previous cells where they are defined and paste them on the cell `In[1]` where I'm having the error, it works fine, but it makes no sense; why would I have to redefine the names on each cell? The exact same thing happens when importing a library, I have to do it on each cell or it doesn't work. This is probably a super basic question but I'm starting to learn and these simple details terrorize me.
Error message: `NameError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-1-698c7414b772> in <module> ----> 1 noise = np.random.uniform(-1,1,(obs,1)) 2 targets = 2*xs - 3*zs + 5 + noise 3 init_range = 0.1 4 weights = np.random.uniform(-init_range,init_range, size=(2,1)) 5 biases = np.random.uniform(-init_range,init_range,size=1) NameError: name 'np' is not defined`
Code:

```
In[4]: import numpy as np
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

In[6]: noise = np.random.uniform(-1,1,(obs,1))
   targets = 2*xs - 3*zs + 5 + noise
   print(targets.shape)

In[7]: import numpy as np
   init_range = 0.1
   weights = np.random.uniform(-init_range,init_range, size=(2,1))
   biases = np.random.uniform(-init_range,init_range,size=1)
   print(weights)
   print(biases)

In[9]: learning_rate = 0.02


In[1]: for i in range (100):
   outputs = np.dot(inputs,weights) + biases
   deltas = outputs - targets

   loss = np.sum(deltas ** 2) / 2 / obs

   print(loss)

   deltas_scaled= deltas/obs

   weights = weights - learning_rate * np.dot(inputs.T,deltas_scaled)
   biases = biases - learning_rate * np.sum(deltas_scaled)
```

I expected the algorithm to show the decreasing values with the learning rate I defined, which it did, but after making me define everything again. I hope I explained well.

Comment: I predict that there is more to the error message than : "NameError: name ' ' is not defined".  Could you copy/paste the entire error message and traceback? There is incredibly useful information hiding in there.

Comment: Yes of course, here's the entire message: NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-698c7414b772> in <module>
----> 1 noise = np.random.uniform(-1,1,(obs,1))
      2 targets = 2*xs - 3*zs + 5 + noise
      3 init_range = 0.1
      4 weights = np.random.uniform(-init_range,init_range, size=(2,1))
      5 biases = np.random.uniform(-init_range,init_range,size=1)

NameError: name 'np' is not defined

Comment: Excellent! this kind of information should be in almost every Stack Overflow question you ask  (it will help you get correct answers fast).  Could you edit this information into your question? That makes it easier for others to learn from your question.

Comment: Cool! Sorry, I'm new in this community, I've fixed my problem but I'll edit the message into my question so others can read my information if they have a similar problem. Cheers!